# Responsive CSS don't apply on smartphone

Tags: css, responsive, mobile-devices

I had to create a specific CSS file to turn an old website into responsive design compatibility. Problem is, even though the new styles apply on a desktop browser (when downsizing the window) it doesn't seem to load on the smartphones.

I used @media queries like this :

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px)
    {
     /* CSS */
    }
```

Also tried differents variations and size, without success.

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 900px)
{
    /* CSS */
}
```

As this is an old website weirdly coded there might be an incompatibilty somewhere but I don't get why it'll work on the desktop anyway. Of course I tried to empty the cache and all without success.

Here's the website : http://www.antiquaire-du-vitrail.com/

Got any idea what the problem could be ?

Comment: maybe it's just a cache. Try opening on your smartphone in incognito mode.

Comment: Its better to use bootstrap free framework works approx on every platform.

Comment: I’d start by inserting a `viewport` meta tag ...

Comment: Try adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> to the head of your page. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: you didn't use [viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Comment: Shame on me :( If completely forgot the VIEWPORT meta !
Thanks a lot, that was a quick guess !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the `<meta>` tag in your `<head>` section?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 , maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Secondly I would use @duy nguyen solution too:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px)
{
 /* CSS */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved ! 
I just forgot the VIEWPORT META in the header.
Thanks for your quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px)
{
    /* CSS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px)  { 
/*put your styles here*/ 
}
```

after applying it in your stylesheet  press CTRL+SHIFT+R(It removes brower's cache)

Comment: code does not work on a smartphone, there is no CTRL+SHIFT+R

Comment: that was for Desktop toggle device toolbar

Answer (score 0):

You can add a meta tag inner header on your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
```

And use media queries as needed.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    /*your css doce here...*/
}

/*or*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    /*your css doce here...*/
}
```

You cad add `min-height`, `max-height` as needed